# SAS fdelete macro wont delete .xml files

Tags: xml, sas

I have a macro that is looping through a set of folders on the file system and deleting either .txt or .xml files:

```
%macro delete_all_txt_files_in_folder(folder, type);


        %macro dummy;


        %mend dummy;


        filename filelist "&folder";

        data _null_;

            dir_id = dopen('filelist');
            total_members = dnum(dir_id);

            if total_members = . then total_members = 0;

            do i = 1 to total_members; 

                member_name = dread(dir_id,i);

                if scan(lowcase(member_name),2,'.')='&type.' then do; 

                    file_id = mopen(dir_id,member_name,'i',0);

                    if file_id > 0 then do; 

                        freadrc = fread(file_id);
                        rc = fclose(file_id);
                        rc = filename('delete',member_name,,,'filelist');
                        rc = fdelete('delete');

                    end;

                    rc = fclose(file_id);

                end;

            end;

            rc = dclose(dir_id);

        run;


    %mend;


    %delete_all_txt_files_in_folder(&rback_4., txt);
    %delete_all_txt_files_in_folder(&rback_5., xml);
    %delete_all_txt_files_in_folder(&rback_6., txt);
    %delete_all_txt_files_in_folder(&rback_7., txt);
```

...however it does not want to delete the .xml files for some reason and I am not really sure why. Is there are restriction on what types of files `fdelete` can remove?

Thanks

Comment: There are no restrictions on fdelete for file types AFAIK. Are you getting an error message? Can you manually delete those files?

Comment: Why does the macro need to read from the file before deleting it?

Comment: Perhaps this is a file permissions issue. Have you checked if the XML files have different permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Macro expressions are not evaluated inside of single quotes.
Change

```
'&type.'
```

to

```
"&type."
```

Comment: If that was the issue, it should't work for any file though?

Answer (score 0):

Macro variables do not resolve in single quotes (unless using, for example, `%BQUOTE('&VAR')`)

```
if scan(lowcase(member_name),2,'.')='&type.' then do;
```

needs to be

```
if scan(lowcase(member_name),2,'.')="&type." then do;
```